# How do you turn an Array of codepoints (Int32) to a string?

Tags: string, crystal-lang, codepoint

In Crystal, a String can be turned into an Array(Int32) of codepoints:

```
"abc".codepoints # [97,98,99]
```

Is there a way to turn the Array back into a String?

Answer (score 3):

```
  str     = "aа€æ∡"
  arr     = str.codepoints              # Array(Int32)
  new_str = arr.map { |x| x.chr }.join

  puts str
  puts new_str
  puts(str == new_str)
```

The [.chr instance method](http://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.23.0/int#chr-instance-method)  can be used to get the Unicode codepoint of an Int. You  then `.join` the individual chars into a new String.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
arr   = "abc".codepoints

# The line below allocates memory and returns a "safe" pointer (ie slice) to it.
# The allocated memory is on the heap with size:
#    arr.size * sizeof(0_u8)
#    sizeof(0_u8) == 8 bits
# A slice of uint8 values (i.e. `Slice(UInt8)`) is aliased
#    in Crystal as `Bytes`.
bytes = Slice.new(arr.size, 0_u8) 
# You can also use the alias: Bytes.new(arr.size, 0_u8)

arr.each_with_index { |v, i|
  bytes[i] = v.to_u8
}
puts String.new(bytes).inspect # => "abc"
```

However, the above fails for multi-byte codepoints: "a€æ∡"